# C++0x decltype fails to deduce member variable constness

Tags: c++, constants, c++11, decltype

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
};

template <typename T>
B<T> f(T& t)
{
    return B<T>();
}

class A
{
    class C {};
    C c;
public:
    A() {}

    decltype(f(c)) get_c() const { return f(c); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.get_c();
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error:

```
test.cpp: In member function 'B<A::C> A::get_c() const':
test.cpp:31:46: error: conversion from 'B<const A::C>' to non-scalar type 'B<A::C>' requested
```

It seems that in the decltype, the compiler doesn't know that this is a const member function and therefore `c` is of type `const C`, and as a result incorrectly deduces the type of `f(c)` to be `B<C>` rather than `B<const C>` which is what it really is.

Am I doing something incorrectly, or is this a compiler bug? I use gcc 4.6, but 4.4 and 4.5 exhibit the same behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler operates correctly according to the current C++0x WP. See [this issue report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1207), which is currently being worked on.

Possibly the final C++0x Standard won't change the meaning of your `decltype` application in the return type before the function name. You would need to move it to after the parameter list using `-> decltype(f(c))`, which hopefully will do The Right thing in final C++0x.

Comment: Do note that C++11 *does* incorporate the fix, so you can use the trailing syntax to get proper const correctness.

Answer (score 0):

No, `decltype` is not supposed to take into account whether the function is const or not, because it can't. The same could have been written differently:

```
typedef decltype(f(c)) return_type;

return_type get_c() const { return f(c); }
```

Correction: `decltype(f(c))` shouldn't even compile, because `c` is not static.

Comment: Yes it should compile. In unevaluated contexts you can access non-static data-members.

Comment: @Johannes, I might be wrong, but as far as I remember access to non-static members only allowed inside the function body. If the function above is modified to use trailing return type, then you can have access to non-static members.

Comment: Yes, I think you're wrong. See my answer to a related quesition here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849556/does-c0x-allow-decltype-in-function-signature/4850444#4850444

Comment: @TonyK, the fact that it compiles under g++ 4.4 isn't a proof of standard conformance. The standard specifies in 9.3.1/3 that access to non-static members is allowed only from inside the function body, so trailing return type is necessary in this case.

Comment: N3225 does not say that. Read it closely, then you will see that it doesn't. Also cf 5.1.1/10.

Answer (score 0):

f needs to take an rvalue reference, not an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're allowed to use decltype on anything you wouldn't normally be able to call.  I haven't been able to find anything in the standard that would allow you to access c, even within a decltype expression, outside of anywhere you could use c.  Since you don't have a `this` pointer at the point you're trying to do your thing, I don't think you can do what you're trying to do.  Doing so doesn't work in MSVC 2010 at least, and it has nothing to do with const.

I considered using declval to get one but you can't access A&&.c because A is an incomplete type at that point.  I can't see anyway to do what you're trying to do other than something like so:

```
decltype(f(declval<C const>())) get_c() const { ... }
```

Comment: The respective text is at 5.1.1/10 last bullet.

Comment: MSVC does not have this because it's working to an earlier Standard draft.